# Another interpretation for $y$

Tags: regression

I calculated a regression line of the formula $y = 9.8x - 2.666$

Where $y =$ calories burned, and $x =$ time (in minutes)

John plans to exercise for $10$ minutes today. Predict the total number of calories burned.

I found the answer to be $95.333$ calories burned, but I don't understand part $2$ of this question.

Give another interpretation for the value computed in part ($1$).

What does it mean by "another interpretation"?